# Android - Dealing with bitmaps allocated in a Vector class

Tags: android, bitmap, heap-memory

So basically, I have a Vector class in which all bitmaps are stored so that I can have a dynamic array. What I actually do is something like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.decodeResource(context.getResources(), context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", "com.example.dynamicbitmap");
vector.add(bmp);
```

What I would like to ask is that.. if I call `vector.remove(value)`, would it free some space in heap space? In short, would the bitmap be automatically recycled? Or do I have to manually invoke it before removing the bitmap object from the vector?

Comment: side note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not free up the memory immediately. Obsolete bitmap will be GC'ed whenever GarbageCollector decides to do it. So basically you don't have to call `recycle()`, but you can end up with `OutOfMemoryException` if you will run out memory.

If you want to free up memory ASAP - you need to call `recycle()` though